# Summation of infinite series when there's index in numerator

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$ \sum_{i = 0}^\infty\frac {i}{(1+y)^i}$$
I know the summation of infinite series when there is no $i$ in the numerator. 
 Can any one help me with this?

Comment: write $x = 1/(1+y)$

Answer (score 1):

Your series can be expressed as $-(1+y)\frac{d}{dy}\sum_{i\ge 0} (1+y)^{-i}$. After some simplifications, you get that
$$\sum_{i\ge 0}\frac i {(1+y)^i}=\frac{1+y}{y^2}.$$